# Web Server and Database Server in a Docker Container

Tags: security, docker, xampp, webserver, database-server

I am quite new to Docker and was wondering if there is any possible way I can find out how a Docker would be used to secure a Web Server and a Database Server. I have Apache Web Server and MySQL Database Server up and running and perfectly functioning (I am using XAMPP).

I just want to know if there is any way I can use Docker to secure the data saved in the Database Server (data = Username and password of users who log in to my website).

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"? Are you concerned about a lack of security offered by your current setup? Or are you trying to understand how DB credentials are shared between two containers?